# Stabilizing a Robot Arm at a Specified Height

Tags: mobile-robot, control, robotic-arm

I have a 4-bar linkage arm (or similar design) for a telerobot used in the [VEX Robotics Competition](http://vexrobotics.com).  I want to be able to press buttons on my PS3-style controller to have the arm raise to certain angles.  I have a potentiometer to measure the 4-bar's angle.

The potentiometer measures the angle of one of the joints in the shoulder of the mechanism, which is similar to this:

[image]

What type of control should I use to stabilize the arm at these angles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case for a [PID controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).  The "derivative" part of this controller will help prevent the arm from oscillating as you move to a new angle, and the "integral" part will help counteract the force of gravity acting on the arm.